# Why Shopify entity ids increase by 4 every time when I create new entity?

Tags: shopify

When I create pages with Shopify Api I noticed that id values increase by 4 every time I create new page.

**For Example:**

```
13911113, 13911117, 13911121...
```

I can't understand why they increase id values by four? Is there a good reason for doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of [database sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29).